# Spring, Skipped (empty) config file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm running spring in debug mode, and after struggling to get it to recognize an external properties file I finally got it to do so

```
Loaded config file 'file:C:/Users/udyj/git/hermes-mq-tool.lib/rte/application-ALD-INT.properties'
```

However right after that line

```
Skipped (empty) config file 'file:C:/Users/udyj/git/hermes-mq-tool.lib/rte/application-ALD-INT.properties'
```

The thing is though, it isn't empty

```
Name=ALD-INT
Queues=
QueueManager=whatever
TAS_MQS_PASSWORD=pw
TAS_MQS_USER=name
```

I'm running spring this way,

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(java, "-noverify", "-cp", classpath, 
            String.format("-Dspring.config.location=%s", "C:\\Users\\udyj\\git\\hermes-mq-tool.lib\\rte\\application-ALD-INT.properties"),
            clazz.getCanonicalName()
            );
```

What does the empty config file thing mean?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: having the same issue here, dont know why it keeps telling file is empty when is not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5147)

> The misleading logging is an unfortunate side-effect of it being
>   performed in a generic location that doesn't (and shouldn't)
>   understand the difference between .properties and .yaml configuration
>   files.